# Уменьшение объема кода и его оптимизация

Tags: python, json, if, for

Есть код, который проверяет, есть ли в файле 'users_id.json' id пользователя. Если id находится, то цикл прерывается. Если цикл логически подошел к концу, то добавляется id нового пользователя. Вопрос первый - возможно ли уменьшить данный кусок кода и нужно ли это? Второй - не много ли ресурсов съедает данный фрагмент кода?
P.S. пишу telegram бота. В будущем на месте этого кода будет запрос к БД. Пока решил сделать так, так как пока что не имею представления, как работать с БД. В программировании начинающий.

```
    with open('users_id.json', 'r') as file:                 # ________________________________________________________
    data = json.load(file)                                   #
    for i in range(len(data['users'])):                      #
        if (len(data['users']) == 0):                        #
            new_user_id = {'id': message.chat.id}            #
            data['users'].append(new_user_id)                #
            break                                            #
                                                             #
        if (data['users'][i]['id'] == message.chat.id):      #
            break                                            # Is user id in database?
        else:                                                #
            if (i == len(data['users']) - 1):                #
                new_user_id = {'id': message.chat.id}        #
                data['users'].append(new_user_id)            #
                break                                        #
            else:                                            #
                continue                                     #
    with open('users_id.json', 'w') as file:                 #
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)  # ________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Самая очевидная оптимизация - убрать псевдографику справа от кода. Это значительно уменьшит количество работы по ее выравниванию после каждой правки кода.

Comment: `if (len(data['users']) == 0):` - и как это сработает, если цикл при таком условии не выполнится ни разу, управление до этого `if` просто не дойдёт

Comment: А вместо этого условия `if (i == len(data['users']) - 1):` лучше написать `for ... else:` вот тут после `else` код без всяких проверок. Только это надо правильно согласовать с первым условием, возможно его нужно тут же в `else` проверять